# Android: Multiple Streaming Variables to Raspberry Pi (Bi-Communication)

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to create an android controller app that will send seekbar data for a steering wheel, brakes, and throttle to the raspberry pi. I've been using TCP/IP over ethernet to communicate with the pi, but I need a way to identify the different data streams associated with the seekbars. I've looked into JeroMQ, and Java Object Serialization but would like to get some suggestions. Ultimately, I need to send, and receive data to/from the Pi, essentially, the data needs to be synced, so that if, let's say, the steering wheel moves in the Pi program, the android also receives that data, and vice versa. Thanks Wizards.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a framework like MQTT or JeroMQ(ZeroMQ) to send the messages, either one will allow you to publish and subscribe, so you don't have to worry about creating a parser, this works particularly well when you need data being communicated bilaterally.

[JeroMQ](https://www.novoda.com/blog/minimal-zeromq-client-server/)

[MQTT](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/)